# How are hydrogen atoms formed in hydrogen discharge tube?

Tags: spectroscopy

I (partially) understand how a breakdown voltage is applied, then the gas is ionized to cations and electrons. Then the electrons will accelerate to the cathode and knock off more electrons from other H2, creating a current ( which is the flow of electrons ). The electrons might excite the gas and the gas emit light as it goes back to normal state. If that the case the shouldn’t in hydrogen discharge tube, the spectral lines observed are those of hydrogen molecules (the gas)? And how does it atomize to give the hydrogen spectral lines?

Comment: Because of all those energetic electrons flying around and hitting things. You get excited H2, atomic H, higher order molecules like H3, all can be excited or ionized or whatnot. But, you have lots of H, so lots of H emission lines.

Comment: additionally to @Jon Custer's comment, $\ce{H2}$ lowest excited state emission is at approx $110 $ nm which is in the far UV so not detectable by our eyes. However, H atoms emit in the visible; search for Balmer Series to see list of values.